# paper rock scissor - Global Variable?

Tags: python, global

Why is this not working?  Do I need to assign global variables?  It's saying `player1` not defined!

```
options=["p", "s", "r"]

def valid1():
    validationa = True
    while validationa==True:
        player1=input("player 1.. Take your go")
        if player1 not in options:
            print ("invalid")
        else:
            validationa==False
            return player1

def valid2():
    validationb = True
    while validationb==True:
        player2=input("player 2.. Take your go")
        if player2 not in options:
            print ("invalid")
        else:
            validationb==False
            return player2
valid1()
valid2()

if player1=="p" and player2 =="p":
    print("Draw")
else:
    print("works but unfinished")
```

Comment: Global variables is an option, but frowned upon. Create a class.

Comment: `valid1()` -> `player1 = valid1()` (and similar for `valid2`)

Comment: Avoid code duplication. Why have two functions `valid1` and `valid2` when one could solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Your functions return values, but you never assign them to anything.

```
player1 = valid1()
player2 = valid2()
```

In fact, these functions do nearly the exact same thing, if you make the text either dynamic or more generic you could have a single function and just call it twice

```
player1 = valid()
player2 = valid()
```

Answer (score 1):

You return player1 and player2 but you don't assign it.

```
options=["p", "s", "r"]

def valid1():
    validationa = True
    while validationa==True:
        player1=input("player 1.. Take your go")
        if player1 not in options:
            print ("invalid")
        else:
            validationa==False
            return player1

def valid2():
    validationb = True
    while validationb==True:
        player2=input("player 2.. Take your go")
        if player2 not in options:
            print ("invalid")
        else:
            validationb==False
            return player2
player1=valid1()
player2=valid2()

if player1=="p" and player2 =="p":
    print("Draw")
else:
    print("works but unfinished")
```

And your functions are almost the same...

```
def valid():
    validation = True
    while validation==True:
        player=input("player.. Take your go")
        if player not in options:
            print ("invalid")
        else:
            validation==False
            return player
```